# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $.getJSON('test1.json', function(data) 
  {
  for (i in data.conferences) {
  var item = data.conferences[i];
  array1.push({
  cid:item.id,
  confName: item.cname,
  confStart:item.start
  }); }
});
```

I use the function for getting values from java to jquery. In chrome and opera shows same error, but it works on IE and mozilla.
Give me a solution for that please.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/winnova1/Desktop/tree/conferences/test1.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'conferences' of null

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, on Chrome and Opera you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` to load local files.
You must run it on a web server, even if that web server is running on `localhost`.

Comment: Sir,I tried using my eclipse server also.I load the file into my eclipse and then add the url to function like this      http://win-pc:2013/Conference/test1.json

Comment: @AvinashThadavarthi: You must load the HTML as well as the JSON from the same web server and you must continue to omit the `http://` in the string passed to `getJSON`.